# Executing multiple scripts via Crontab; Continuously repeats and doesnt stop

Tags: cron, ubuntu-server

I have the following cronjob set to execute daily at a specific time:

MAILTO="email address"

- 16 * * * python3 /home/cladkins/NBA.py && python3 /home/cladkins/NCAABB.py && python3 /home/cladkins/NCAAFB.py

added this via `sudo nano crontab`,`crontab -e`

It is executing almost to well, this is a case of it doesn't know what to do if you don't tell it what to do. My intention is at 1600 UTC everyday to have these scripts run once. Current behavior is that it just keeps looping forever. How can i get it to execute each script only once?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use lib like [celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) to manage and track the execution of your cron jobs easily.

After setting up the celery, you will end up having something like this:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    # Executes every day at 16:00 
    'my-sample-task': {
        'task': 'tasks.task_name',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=16, minute=0),
        'args': (16, 16),
    },
}
```

Check [this link](http://www.pythondoc.com/celery-3.1.11/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) for more details.